# 'no module named setuptools' but it is contained in the DEPENDS variable

Tags: yocto, openembedded

This Problem regards Openembedded/Yocto.

I have source code which needs to be compiled by a custom python3 script.
That means, that some python3 script should run during the `do_compile()` process.
The script imports setuptools, therefore, I added `DEPENDS += "python3-setuptools-native"` to the recipe. As far as I understand the documentation, this should make the setuptools module available for the building process (native).
But when bitbake executes the `do_compile()` process, I get this error: `no module named 'setuptools'`.

Let me break it down to a minimal (non-)working example:

FILE: **test.bb**

```
LICENSE = "BSD"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://test/LICENSE;md5=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"

DEPENDS += "python3-setuptools-native"

SRC_URI = "file://test.py \
           file://LICENSE"

do_compile() {
    python3 ${S}/../test.py
}
```

FILE: **test.py**

```
import setuptools

print("HELLO")
```

bitbaking:

```
$ bitbake test
ERROR: test-1.0-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /path/to/test/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.8532)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /path/to/test/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.8532
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| Traceback (most recent call last):
|   File "/path/to/test-1.0/../test.py", line 1, in <module>
|     import setuptools
| ImportError: No module named 'setuptools'
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /path/to/test/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.8532)
ERROR: Task (/path/to/test.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 400 tasks of which 398 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
NOTE: Writing buildhistory

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /path/to/test.bb:do_compile
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Is my exepectation wrong, that `DEPENDS += "python3-setuptools-native"` makes the python3 module 'setuptools' available to the python3 script in `do_compile()`? How may I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood quite a bit more is needed to get working setuptools support. Luckily there's a class to handle that:

```
inherit setuptools3
```

This should be all that's need to package a setuptools based project with OE-Core. As long as your project has a standard setup.py you don't need to write any do_compile() or do_install() functions.

If you do need to look at the details, `meta/classes/setuptools3.bbclass` and `meta/classes/distutils3.bbclass` should contain what you need (including the rather unobvious way to call native python from a recipe).

Comment: If that doesn't work, please try to inherit `python_setuptools_build_meta` instead of `setuptools3`. Saved me :)